# Python's format doesn't work with text containing JSON

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This code:

```
'From {"value": 1}, value={value}'.format(value=1)
```

Fails like following (Python 2.7.12 and Python 3.6.x):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_format.py", line 1, in <module>
    'From {"value": 1}, value={value}'.format(value=1)
KeyError: '"value"
```

Python interpreter complains that `"value"` wasn't passed in the arguments for `format`method.

But according to the [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html):

```
replacement_field ::=  "{" [field_name] ["!" conversion] [":" format_spec] "}"
field_name        ::=  arg_name ("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")*
arg_name          ::=  [identifier | integer]
attribute_name    ::=  identifier
element_index     ::=  integer | index_string
index_string      ::=  <any source character except "]"> +
conversion        ::=  "r" | "s"
format_spec       ::=  <described in the next section>
```

The **replacement_field**, which in this case, is composed by an **identifier**, shouldn't have *quotation marks*. Here is the lexical definition for an **identifier**:

```
identifier ::=  (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*
letter     ::=  lowercase | uppercase
lowercase  ::=  "a"..."z"
uppercase  ::=  "A"..."Z"
digit      ::=  "0"..."9"
```

So according to the specification, `{value}` should be recognized as a valid format string identifier and `{"value"}` should be ignored.

Python seems to not follow the specification in the documentation. Anything inside the keys is accepted as *identifier*.

Why python behaves like that? What am I missing here?

Comment: Why are you trying to create JSON using `.format()` in the first place? Use the `json` module.

Comment: The `{"value"}` cannot be treated as replacement field because "value" is an expression but not a keyword, the quotation is not allowed.

Comment: @LuCima See the traceback, Python is complaining for an argument named `"value"`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have actual brackets `{}` in your output, you need to do this:

```
'{{"value": 1}}, {}'.format(0)
```

Format treats everythin within brackets `{}` as arguments. Empty brackets mean positional values, everything else is treatet as a keyword argument.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to use format for texts containing valid JSON.

Comment: In this case you should use the `json` module, like @Barmar suggested. Load your valid json via `json.loads()` and modifiy the fields directly. Or use `format()` directly on a field.

Comment: I want to mix formatted values and JSON encoded string in a final string. `json` module cannot do that.